# swagger.json example json for forecast model doesn't seem to return predictions

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

When trying to make predictions for forecasting models using Azure ML Service, the swagger.json includes the following schema for input:

```
"example": {"data": [{"date": "2019-08-30T00:00:00.000Z", "y_query": 1.0}]}
```

However, when I feed this as an input to generate predictions, I receive the following error:

```
data= {"data": [{"date": "2019-08-30T00:00:00.000Z", "y_query": 1 }]}
# Convert to JSON string
input_data = json.dumps(data)

# Set the content type
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
# If authentication is enabled, set the authorization header
#headers['Authorization'] = f'Bearer {key}'

# Make the request and display the response
resp = requests.post(scoring_uri, input_data, headers=headers)
print(resp.text)
```

```
"{\"error\": \"DataException:\\n\\tMessage: y values are present for each date. Nothing to forecast.\\n\\tInnerException None\\n\\tErrorResponse \\n{\\n    \\\"error\\\": {\\n        \\\"code\\\": \\\"UserError\\\",\\n        \\\"inner_error\\\": {\\n            \\\"code\\\": \\\"InvalidData\\\"\\n        },\\n        \\\"message\\\": \\\"y values are present for each date. Nothing to forecast.\\\"\\n    }\\n}\"}"
```

I have tried not passing a y value, which causes an 'expected two axis got one' and passing 0 as the y_query. Any guidance on how to make predictions using this approach would be greatly appreciated.

The documentation for web services is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-consume-web-service

Comment: I'm unaware of any prediction step in AML which raises a 'DataException', so I'm inclined to believe it may be an issue in the driver file. Would you be able to share the code for the driver file that you are using?

Comment: Sure thing. Can you point me in the direction of how to find this? Thank you.

Comment: How did you deploy the webservice? You would have needed to specify an 'entry script' when deploying, that's the file I mean.

Comment: Hey there! So the deployment was handled via the Azure ML Service, where you deploy the best model via the UI, so I haven’t physically manifested the entry script, that has been handled by Azure. I can go through it though?

Comment: Ah, okay. Talked with someone who handles more of that part of things, they said that the error occurs when the provided date is already in the training set that was used for the model. Can you try passing a date that is sometime in the future and see if that works?

Comment: Hey trangevi, I’ve tried this and no such luck. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using nan as the value for y_query. and make sure the date is the next time unit after the one that was used in the training set.

Answer (score 0):

The following way of submitting np.nan worked for me for y_query.

```
input_sample = pd.DataFrame(data=[{'Feature1_text': 'text1', 'Feature2_int': 0, 'Feature3_double': 2.0, 'DateHour': '2019-11-12T04:00:00.000Z', 'y_query': np.nan}])
run(input_sample)
```

As mentioned, make sure the date-time input is for a time after the last date in training, otherwise you would get the following error.

> Input prediction data X_pred or input forecast_destination contains
>   dates prior to the latest date in the training data. Please remove
>   prediction rows with datetimes in the training date range or adjust
>   the forecast_destination date.